# Python regex with negated pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex statement in Python with a negated pattern.  I want to match a pattern that doesn't start with a `U` followed by a `W` and optionally ends with a `1`.  Below are some examples.

```
TUW1TH > # regex does not get applied
JUWRG > # regex does not get applied
BUIUW1 > # regex does not get applied
ATWKO > ATW KO # regex applies and space is added after the W
EWRG > E WRG # regex applies and space is added after the W
AGDTWSD > AGDTW SD # regex applies and space is added after the W
```

Below is the regex statement I tried to use:

```
 re.sub(ur"[^U]W[^?1]", ur"W ", word)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `1?` instead of `[^?1]`?

Comment: Where does the space go if there is a `1` after the `W` (assuming it is not preceeded by a `U`)?  For example, "EW1RG" -> ???.  You didn't give an example of a case like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking to match a 'W' optionally followed by a '1', but only if the 'W' is not preceded by a 'U'.  If that is the case, a "negative look behind" is the answer:

```
import re

testcases = ['TUW1TH', 'JUWRG', 'BUIUW1', 'ATWKO', 'EWRG', 'AGDTWSD', 'W1EF', 'EW1RG']

# The `(W1?)` part matches a 'W' with an optional '1'. The `(?<!U)` part 
#     matches the current position only if it wasn't a preceded by a 'U'
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!U)(W1?)')

for s in testcases:
    print(pattern.sub(r'\1 ', s))
```

outputs:

```
TUW1TH
JUWRG
BUIUW1
ATW KO
EW RG
AGDTW SD
W1 EF
EW1 RG
```

Note: `[^U]` doesn't work at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `[^U]W1?`

You used a character class containing "not ?", instead of the token "optionally a 1".

Answer (score 0):

Try regex pattern `([^U])W1?'` and use it with `re.sub()` with a substitution that references the captured group, like this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([^U]W)1?')
for s in 'TUW1TH', 'JUWRG', 'BUIUW1', 'ATWKO', 'EWRG', 'AGDTWSD':
    print(pattern.sub(r'\1 ', s))
```

**Output**

```
TUW1TH
JUWRG
BUIUW1
ATW KO
EW RG
AGDTW SD
```

Note that the output for `'EWRG'` differs from your sample... I think that's a typo in your question?

Your question wasn't clear about what to do with the optional `1` following the `W` and there was no sample to demonstrate. Is the `1` to be removed, or kept? The above code will lose the `1`:

```
>>> print(pattern.sub(r'\1 ', 'TW1TH'))
TW TH
```

If you wanted the output to include the `1`, then you can change the regex pattern to `r'([^U]W)(1?)'` to add a second capturing group for the optional `1`, and change the substitution to r`\1 \2`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([^U]W)(1?)', r'\1 \2', 'TW1TH')
'TW 1TH'
```